# Save Notification Data in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging, uikit

Whenever I receive notifications from FCM, I want to save those data. The reason why I am saving this is to show a table view of the received notification. I found out that there are many ways to save data. For example, UserDefaults, CoreData, and FileManager, etc. I want to know what is the most suitable way to save data.
The data is a struct with 3 string properties. It should be saved even when the app is killed. It can be deleted when a user deletes certain data from the tableview.

Comment: For saving the data above can you advise me which option is suitable?? I'm new to do this ,,

Comment: There are many tutorials if you could search, it depends on many factors like size, sensitive data, should they persist if you delete the app etc. If you don't care about sensitivity, and its a small data, you can rely on user defaults.

Comment: You can’t do anything if the app is killed. Your best bet is to use Firestore. Send the notification and save the data at the same time with a FirebaseFunction.